# I cannot login to my admin panel after migrating my WordPress Website to another host

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just migrated my website to  Namecheap and it all went on fine, I can see the live URL of my website and it is doing alright, the problems comes up when I go to the admin section of my and input my credentials get errors.

Here are some of the things I have tried.

1. Removing old plugins/
2. Removing the htaccess file.
3. Creating a new admin via the PHP admin.
4. Removing old themes[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I was able to do after many trials and errors.

If the other solutions listed above won't work, then try the Emergency Password Reset Script. It is not a Plugin. It is a PHP script.

Warnings

1. Requires you know the administrator username.
2. It updates the administrator password and sends an email to the administrator's email address.
3. If you don't receive the email, the password is still changed.
4. You do not need to be logged in to use it.
5. If you could log in, you wouldn't need the script.

Here is how to use this script -

1. Place the code below in the root of your WordPress installation, I mean in the public_html folder, the same directory that contains wp-config.php. Save the script below as a file called emergency.php to the root of your WordPress installation
2. As soon as you are done uploading the script, log in to my_website.com/emergency.php
3. As instructed, enter the administrator username (usually admin) and the new password, then click Update Options.
4. Delete the script when you are done for security reasons.
   Directions for use

A message is displayed noting the changed password. An email is sent to the blog administrator with the changed password information.

Delete emergency.php from your server when you are done. Do not leave it on your server as someone else could use it to change your password.

```
<?php
/*
    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
        it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
        the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
        (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
        but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
        MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
        GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
        along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
        Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

require './wp-blog-header.php';

function meh() {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_POST['update'] ) ) {
        $user_login = ( empty( $_POST['e-name'] ) ? '' : sanitize_user( $_POST['e-name'] ) );
        $user_pass  = ( empty( $_POST[ 'e-pass' ] ) ? '' : $_POST['e-pass'] );
        $answer = ( empty( $user_login ) ? '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>The user name field is empty.</strong></p></div>' : '' );
        $answer .= ( empty( $user_pass ) ? '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>The password field is empty.</strong></p></div>' : '' );
        if ( $user_login != $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_login FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID = '1' LIMIT 1" ) ) {
            $answer .="<div id='message' class='updated fade'><p><strong>That is not the correct administrator username.</strong></p></div>";
        }
        if ( empty( $answer ) ) {
            $wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->users SET user_pass = MD5('$user_pass'), user_activation_key = '' WHERE user_login = '$user_login'" );
            $plaintext_pass = $user_pass;
            $message = __( 'Someone, hopefully you, has reset the Administrator password for your WordPress blog. Details follow:' ). "\r\n";
            $message  .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __( 'Password: %s' ), $plaintext_pass ) . "\r\n";
            @wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), sprintf( __( '[%s] Your WordPress administrator password has been changed!' ), get_option( 'blogname' ) ), $message );
            $answer="<div id='message' class='updated fade'><p><strong>Your password has been successfully changed</strong></p><p><strong>An e-mail with this information has been dispatched to the WordPress blog administrator</strong></p><p><strong>You should now delete this file off your server. DO NOT LEAVE IT UP FOR SOMEONE ELSE TO FIND!</strong></p></div>";
        }
    }

    return empty( $answer ) ? false : $answer;
}

$answer = meh();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>WordPress Emergency PassWord Reset</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo( 'html_type' ); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-admin/wp-admin.css?version=<?php bloginfo( 'version' ); ?>" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <h2>WordPress Emergency PassWord Reset</h2>
            <p><strong>Your use of this script is at your sole risk. All code is provided "as -is", without any warranty, whether express or implied, of its accuracy, completeness. Further, I shall not be liable for any damages you may sustain by using this script, whether direct, indirect, special, incidental or consequential.</strong></p>
            <p>This script is intended to be used as <strong>a last resort</strong> by WordPress administrators that are unable to access the database.
                Usage of this script requires that you know the Administrator's user name for the WordPress install. (For most installs, that is going to be "admin" without the quotes.)</p>
            <?php
            echo $answer;
            ?>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Options" /></p>

            <fieldset class="options">
                <legend>WordPress Administrator</legend>
                <label><?php _e( 'Enter Username:' ) ?><br />
                    <input type="text" name="e-name" id="e-name" class="input" value="<?php echo attribute_escape( stripslashes( $_POST['e-name'] ) ); ?>" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="options">
                    <legend>Password</legend>
                    <label><?php _e( 'Enter New Password:' ) ?><br />
                    <input type="text" name="e-pass" id="e-pass" class="input" value="<?php echo attribute_escape( stripslashes( $_POST['e-pass'] ) ); ?>" size="25" tabindex="20" /></label>
                </fieldset>

                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Options" /></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php exit; ?>
```